# Office Web Add-in cache not clearing

Tags: caching, microsoft-edge, add-in

I have created a few Word Office Web Add-ins and when I run the code either in debug or non-debug after making changes to html or JavaScript the cache does not clear running it from Visual Studio Pro 2019.

This is very frustrating as I cannot debug my code very well. Sometime if I wait 45 minutes it clears. I've cleared MS Edge file cache and still the same issue.

It seems VS 2019 is not clearing or updating the code stored in IIS Express or what ever web server it uses locally.

Anybody have this issue and fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set no-caching headers in the HTML page and again try to test the issue to check the result.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```